# Login and Registration php program

Tags: php

I want to know what/where to put code for my checkLogin.php, so that when I click register it takes them to the register form. I am unsure about where I should put the code or what commands should be used to make it so that when the register button is clicked it doesn't tell me that I ahve not filled in hte username or password.

checkLogin.php:

```
<?php
/* connection info */
ini_set("display_errors","on");
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("include_path","../../includes");
include("dbinfo.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) 
    or die("Couldn't connect to server.");

?>
<?php
/*  Program name: checkLogin.php 
 *  Description:  Program displays the blank form and checks 
 *  all the form fields for blank fields.
 */
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) and $_POST['submitted'] == "yes")
{
  foreach($_POST as $field => $value)           
  {
    if(empty($value))
      {
         $blank_array[] = $field;
      }
    else                                                    
    {
      $good_data[$field] = strip_tags(trim($value));
    }
  } 

  if(@sizeof($blank_array) > 0) 
  {
    $message = "<p style='color: red; margin-bottom: 0; 
                 font-weight: bold'>
                 You didn't fill in one or more required fields. 
                 You must enter: 
                 <ul style='color: red; margin-top: 0; 
                 list-style: none' >";

 /* display list of missing information */
    foreach($blank_array as $value)
    {
       $message .= "<li>$value</li>";
    }
    $message .= "</ul>"; 

    echo $message;
    extract($good_data);
    include("login.inc");   
    exit();    
  }

  foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
{
  if(!empty($value))
  {
    $user_patt = "/^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,20}$/";
    $pass_patt = "/^[A-Za-z0-9*!@$&]{8,12}$/";

    if(preg_match("/user/i",$field))
    {
      if(!preg_match($user_patt,$value))
      {
        $error_array[] = "$value is an invalid $field";
      }
    }

    if (preg_match("/pass/i",$field))
    {
        if(!preg_match($pass_patt, $value))
        {   
            $error_array[] = "Invalid $field";  
        }
     }
  } 

  $clean_data[$field] = strip_tags(trim($value));

}

if(@sizeof($error_array) > 0) 
{

  $message = "<ul style='color: red; list-style: none' >";
  foreach($error_array as $value)
  {
   $message .= "<li>$value</li>";
  }
  $message .= "</ul>"; 

  echo $message;
  extract($clean_data);
  include("login.inc");
  exit();   
}
 else
    {
    foreach($good_data as $field => $value)
        {
            $clean_data[$field] = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$value);
        }
    $sql = "SELECT * from UserInfo where username='$clean_data[username]' and
        password='$clean_data[password]'";
        $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql) or die("<p>Couldn't connect to login server</p>");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row > 0)
        {
            $sql2 = "UPDATE TimeStamp SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where username='$clean_data[username]'";  
               $result2 = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql2) or die("<p>Couldn't connect to login server</p>");
            include('goodLogin.inc');
        }
        else
        {
            echo $message;
            extract($clean_data);
            include('login.inc');
            exit();
        } 
    }   
}
else
{
  include("login.inc");
}   
?>
```

login.inc:

```
<?php
    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='POST'>";
    echo "<h2>Login Form</h2>";

foreach ( $labels as $field => $label)

    if($field != "password")
    {
        echo "<div class='field'>
                <label for='$field'>$label</label>
                    <input id='$field' name='$field' type='text' value='".@$$field."'
                        size='42' /></div>";
    } 
        else 
                {
                    echo "<div class='field'>
                        <label for='$field'>$label</label>
                        <input id='$field' name='$field' type='password' maxlength='20' value='".@$$field."' size='42' />";
                    echo "</div>";
                }

        echo "<div id='submit'>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' value='yes'>
            <input type='submit' value='$login'></div>
            <h4>If you are new click register</h4>";

        echo "<div id='register'>
            <input type='submit' value='$register' a href='register.php'></div>";
        echo "</form>";
?>
```

Register.php:

```
<?php
/* Program name: form_inc
 * Description:  Defines the Form to display a user's information
 */
$labels = array (
    "username" => "Username",
    "password" => "Password",
    "first_name" => "First Name",
    "last_name" => "Last Name",
    "city" => "City",
    "email" => "E-mail",);

$country = array (
    "select" => "",
    "us" => "United States",
    "ca" => "Canada",
    "mx" => "Mexico", );    

$register = "Register";
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Exercise 3 Order Form</title>
<style type=>
    form {
        margin: 5em auto 8em;
        padding: 0; 
    }
    h2 {
        text-align: center; 
    }
    form {
        float: left;
        width: 450px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border: solid 2px #CCC;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .field {
        padding-top: .5em;
        padding-botton: 2em;    
    }
    label {
        font-weight: bold;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        margin-right: 1em;
        text-align: right;
    }   
    #submit {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 2%;    
    }
    #register {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 2%;
        margin-right: 2.5%; 
    }
    h4 {
        margin-left: 42%;   
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='POST'>";
    echo "<h2>Registration Form</h2>";
    foreach ( $labels as $field => $label)
    {
        echo "<div class='field'>
                <label for='$field'>$label</label>
                    <input id='$field' name='$field' type='text' value='".@$$field."'
                        size='42' /></div>";
        if($field == "city") {
            echo "<div class='field'>";

            echo "<label for='country'>Country</label>
                    <select id='country' name='country'>";

                foreach ( $country as $select => $option)
                {
                    echo "<option value='$select'>$option</option>";
                }

            echo "</select></div>";
        }
    }
        echo "<div id='register'>
            <input type='submit' value='$register'></div>";
        echo "</form>";
?>
```

Comment: First of all what's your problem? Please specify with simple line and also put full code . not the part of it. it will be much better if you comment your problem in the code itself. thanks

Comment: I am not sure how or where to put the part that tells the program to take out the login form and put in the registration.inc form instead?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing the full code. You've posted a block of code that begins with `else{` and that's just no bueno.

Comment: What does `goodLogin.inc` do? Make a session for active user? If so then if POST or GET isn't set and SESSION isnt set include login form. If POST is set then test login and process error or sucess.

Comment: means if user not register then go to registration page otherwise login will happen?

Comment: That is the problem. as for the other code I already stated what it was and that it was irrelevant to what was needed I want to know how after the last exit command and before the final include("login.inc"); How i can make it so that when the register button is clicked it removes the login.inc and repalces it with the register.inc

Comment: (goodlogin.inc) simply states that the login was successful nothing more than that

Comment: `@Jason Cameron` if it based on button click that you want to change form or to go to that particular form location, then give different name and value  to login and register button and check it through `$_POST` or `$_GET` what ever method is used? if that button name and value is present then go to that form.

Comment: It is through the $_POST The variable for the buttons is in the inc files and stackoverflow gets mad at me if I try to include too much code. I am using the form action $_SERVER[PHP SELF] The rest of the program first checks for blank fields (if empty then put into checkblank array) if the array is > then 0 then the login is unsuccessful. Then it uses pregmatch to check format of the username and password. if format is incorrect then the login fails.

Comment: After that if the login is successful it checks the MySQL database for username and password. if it exists it logs in successfully(include= goodlogin.inc) If its not then it displays an error message

Comment: After that code posted above, but before the last include (login.inc) I want to make it so that when the register button is clicked it includes register.inc  not login.inc. Is this accomplished in this code which is checkLogin.php, or do I change it in the register.inc file where the code is:

Comment: echo "<div id='register'>
   <input type='submit' value='$register'></div>";
  echo "</form>";
?>

Comment: the problem that you are not helping youreself. show atleast how's your button is look like and how's your form look like through an image link. or if you are working live then give live url

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your entire login or signup system into one file, or say better into a namespace:

```
namespace myfile;
class Membership {
     public function exists() { returns true/false; }
     public function signup() { returns true/false; }
     public function signin() { returns true/false; }
}
```

and connect to your namespace by including:

```
require 'membership.php';
use Membership as ms;
$obj = new ms\membership ();
$obj->signup(array('username'=>'' ,'password' => ''));
```

and work along with your library instead of seperation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a stab in the dark here, but you've got register button, let's pretend it looks like this:

```
<a href="mylogin.php?register">Register</a>
```

See how I added the `?register` part to the URL?

Then you can do:

```
include isset($_GET['register']) ? "register.inc" : "login.inc";
```

Comment: That makes more sense to me yes, but if the register button code looks like this? How would I incorporate the above?

echo "<div id='register'> <input type='submit' value='$register'></div>"; echo "</form>";

Comment: I do apologize if I am being unclear, I am giving what I have been taught as this is a college course and I am beginning to think it may or not be outdated, but this is how they want it for the project so this is how I am doing it.